# I Keep getting 'NotReadablePropertyException' when running a unit test against a new Spring Validator class

Tags: java, spring, spring-validator

I am creating a basic login page via Spring MVC. So far, I have created the following:

- A simple 'login' POJO class
- A 'LoginValidator' class which implements the spring interface: org.springframework.validation.Validator
- A 'LoginValidatorTests' class

My Unit test fails with the below exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'login' of bean class [springapp.service.LoginValidator]: Bean property 'login' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:707)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:699)
    at org.springframework.validation.AbstractPropertyBindingResult.getActualFieldValue(AbstractPropertyBindingResult.java:99)
    at org.springframework.validation.AbstractBindingResult.rejectValue(AbstractBindingResult.java:105)
    at springapp.service.LoginValidator.validateUsername(LoginValidator.java:44)
    at springapp.service.LoginValidator.validate(LoginValidator.java:27)
    at springapp.service.LoginValidatorTests.testEmptyUsernameAndPassword(LoginValidatorTests.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:164)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:130)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:106)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.JUnit3TestReference.run(JUnit3TestReference.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Code snippers below.

1. Login.java:

   package springapp.service;

   ```
   import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
   import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;


   public class Login{

       /** Logger for this class and subclasses */
       protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

       private String username;
       private String password;

       public void setUsername(String username){
           this.username = username;
       }

       public String getUsername(){
           return username;
       }

       public void setPassword(String password){
           this.password = password;
       }

       public String getPassword(){
           return password;
       }

   }
   ```
2. LoginValidator.java

   ```
   package springapp.service;

   import org.springframework.validation.Validator;
   import org.springframework.validation.Errors;

   import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
   import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

   //import springapp.domain.Login;

   public class LoginValidator implements Validator {

       /** Logger for this class and subclasses */
       protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

       public boolean supports(Class clazz) {
           return Login.class.equals(clazz);
       }

       public void validate(Object obj, Errors errors) {
           Login login = (Login) obj;

           if (login == null) {
               errors.rejectValue("login", "error.username-and-password-required", null, "Value required.");
           }
           //validate username
           validateUsername(login, errors);

           //if no errors, validate password
           if (!errors.hasErrors()){
               validatePassword(login, errors);
           }           
       }

       private boolean validateUsername(Login login, Errors errors){
           String username = login.getUsername();

           if (username == null || username.length() == 0){
               errors.rejectValue("login", "error.username-required", null, "Value required.");
               return false;
           }

           if (username != "admin") {
               errors.rejectValue("login", "error.username-not-found", null, "Value required.");
               return false;
           }

           return true;
       }

       private boolean validatePassword(Login login, Errors errors){
           String password = login.getPassword();

           if (password == null || password.length() == 0){
               errors.rejectValue("login", "error.password-required", null, "Value required.");
               return false;
           }

           if (password != "admin") {
               errors.rejectValue("login", "error.password-invalid", null, "Value required.");
               return false;
           }

           return true;        
       }   

   }
   ```
3. LoginValidatorTests.java. When running the unit test 'testEmptyUsernameAndPassword', I get the exception:

   ```
   package springapp.service;

   import junit.framework.TestCase;

   import springapp.service.LoginValidator;

   import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
   import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

   import org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult;
   import org.springframework.validation.Validator;
   import org.springframework.validation.Errors;

   public class LoginValidatorTests extends TestCase {

       protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());
       private LoginValidator loginValidator = new LoginValidator();
       private Login login= new Login();
       private Errors errors = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(loginValidator, "loginValidator");

       public void testEmptyUsernameAndPassword(){
           login.setPassword("ee");
           login.setUsername("ee");
           loginValidator.validate(login, errors);

           assertTrue(errors.hasErrors());
           //assertTrue(errors.getFieldError().toString().contains("error.username-and-password-required"));
       }

       public void testEmptyUsernameOnly(){

       }

       public void testEmptyPasswordOnly(){

       }

       public void testInvalidUsername(){

       }

       public void testInvalidPassword(){

       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Where is application context ?

Comment: Please post the rest of the stack trace. @Youngistan An `ApplicationContext` is not necessary here.

Comment: Do you mean the *servlet.xml file?

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis, I have updated my post to include the full stack trace.

Comment: Your property name is `password` not `login`, change first parameter of `rejectValue` to `login`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First

```
private Errors errors = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(loginValidator, "loginValidator");
```

should be

```
private Errors errors = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(login, "login" /* or whatever name */);
```

otherwise the target object for your `Errors` is the `LoginValidator` object instead of your `Login` object.

Note the javadoc of [`Errors#rejectValue(..)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/Errors.html#rejectValue-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)

> **field** - the field name (may be null or empty String)

So what you are specifying here

```
errors.rejectValue("login", "error.username-required", null, "Value required.");
```

the value `login` **is actually used as the field name** of the target object's class. But neither your `Login` class nor your `LoginValidator` class have such a field. You should use `username` or `password` where appropriate.

Answer (score -1):

Looking at your stack trace it's pretty likely that your property 'login' at the class 'LoginValidator' does not have the Get and Set method declared, or maybe those methods are not written correctly.

Try to include Get/Set methods to the property 'login' or correct your older ones to return the correct type of the object, both at the class 'LoginValidator', of course.

Comment: Why would they perform bean validation on their non-bean `LoginValidator` class?

Comment: Stack trace hints the following: Invalid property 'login' of bean class [springapp.service.LoginValidator], let's just wait and see if my solution works in it's case. Had some troubles with NotReadablePropertyException at the project I'm working on, and the Get/Set methods solved the situation.

Comment: Yes, your analysis of why the error happens is correct. But your suggested corrections are wrong. You are not looking at the bigger picture.